# can not export a csv file through a rail application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, csv

I am trying to export a csv file through a rail application. I have a previous application which imports the data from a csv file and shows it in the webpage. That application was fired from the url http://localhost:3000/ and it was working fine.

But now I am trying to get back the data shown in the webpage back to a csv file which I can download from the page.

Now I am not sure why I am facing the error. The localhost page is not working
and server is running in a loop.

I think I have some problems with in the user.rb file in all.each do section.

Actually I want to add a csv file download link in the same page.

My code is as follows:-

I created my app name is names
My app\controllers\users_controller.rb file is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def index
 @users=User.all

 @users= User.order(:name)
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to root_url }
  format.csv {send_data @users.to_csv}

 end
```

end
   def import
    User.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Activity data imported!"
    end
    end

My app\models\user.rb file is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
require 'csv'

def self.to_csv(options = {}) 
CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << column_names
      all.each do |name|
        csv << name.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
end
end




def self.import(file)
quote_chars = %w(" | ~ ^ & *)
begin
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: :first_row, quote_char:     quote_chars.shift) do |row|
    User.create! row.to_hash
end

rescue CSV::MalformedCSVError
    quote_chars.empty? ? raise : retry 
 end
end
end
```

My app\views\users\index.html.erb file is:

```
<%= flash[:notice] %>

<p>
Download:
<%= link_to "CSV", names_path(format: "csv") %> |

</p>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= user.age %></td>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
</table>

<div>
<h4>Import the data!</h4>
<%= form_tag import_users_path, multipart: true do %>
<%= file_field_tag :file %>
<%= submit_tag "Import CSV" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

My previous application database screenshot is:-
[image: The columns names are Age and Name respectively]

Comment: I hope I understood you right: It seems you have a NamesController, but your routes are defined for a UsersController. You can find how to configure the correct routes in the [rails guides section, routing from inside out](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: I understand the point and now I am trying to add a download link in the same page. But I am facing a different problem which I have mentioned here.

Comment: Good to hear you could fix your former problem. If you are facing some beginners stuff I'd recommend you to stick to the official rails guides and ask for help via IRC (rails at freenode). The ruby (and rails) community is super friendly and you'll find help for sure. If you are stuck with a very specific problem, Stackoverflow is the right place for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not following Rails conventions. You defined name controller, model and view but you didn't define routes for them. Something like 

`resources :names`

or just for index action

`get '/names' => 'names#index'`

On the other hand you have routes defined for user, with resources :users, so you need to have UsersController(if you have defined users_controller check file name for it, this error may happen if you mistyped name for it).